How to send a user specified number through a link_to, Rails
@uneaten_bananas is an integer, say, and
<%=link_to "Get Bag",get_bag_for_uneaten_bananas_fruitstand_index_path(id:@sale_ticket.id),remote: true%>

I need a rogue collection select 1..@uneaten_bananas for user to pick how many uneaten bananas they want put in the bag, and I need to put that number as a parameter in the link_to ..?
Normally there'd be a form involved, but I'm updating attributes on various bananas after putting them in the bag, for example, not updating any one instance.

If a form is not an option then you are going to need to use JavaScript to send the request. I am assuming you are looking for something like /fruitstand/sale/:id/bag/uneaten_bananas?number_of_bananas=6 but you should update your question to clarify. BTW as you identified a form would be much simpler.

Ok I appreciate that. You mean javascript to trigger a method after a selection is made? ... I've been looking a while and I can't see how to even do a select without a form. Too bad there's no <%= pulldown = select[1..@uneaten_bananas] %> then <%=link_to "Get Bag",get_bag_for_uneaten_bananas_fruitstand_index_path(id:@sale_ticket.id, number_of_bananas: pulldown),remote: true%>

... think you're right, will try a form for @sale_ticket, and do a <%= simple_fields_for :other do |o| %> within it to get the number select in there.

<%= f.simple_fields_for :other do |o| %>. Always use fields_for from the parent form or the keys will be unnested.

Thank you ... I assume nested keys is required for strong params? Can't find anything on this. The key currently is unnested, but the purpose of my form isn't to update any instance. Regardless, I'll change it now

... in the 2 cases I have unnested keys, they are used in if/thens in the controller (not involved in strong params)
